# Can you use System Center Data Protection Manager to back up Azure DevOps Server SQL Server databases?

Tags: sql-server, azure-devops-server-2019

Azure DevOps Server 2019 documentation states two ways to do backups.

You can use the Scheduled Backups tool to configure a backup schedule or back up the databases manually.

If you use System Center Data Protection Manager, do you need to follow the manual backup steps to have a viable backup?

DPM can backup SQL Server databases.

Relevant documentation follows.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/backup/config-backup-sched-plan?view=azure-devops-2019

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/backup/manually-backup-tfs?view=azure-devops-2019

Comment: System Center Data Protection Manager can backup Azure DevOps Server SQL Server databases. You can refer to this document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/system-center/dpm/back-up-sql-server?view=sc-dpm-2019 to Back up SQL Server with DPM regardless of the "Manually back up Azure DevOps Server" document you shared. You can simply protect the databases or additional stuff such as reporting services depending on how your Azure DevOps Server is setup.

Comment: Yes. DPM can backup SQL databases but in the case of the Azure DevOps SQL databases the manual process talks extensively about synchronizing the backups with marked transactions with I don't think DPM does by default. My main concern is will DPM sync the backups or is there a setting in DPM to do that?

Comment: This topic is more biased towards how to use System Center Data Protection Manager. So I suggest you could get support from DPM community: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/home?category=dpm&forum=dpmpowershell&filter=alltypes&sort=lastpostdesc&brandIgnore=true&page=2